# How to display more folder options when creating bookmark in firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

When creating a bookmark in Firefox (say by pressing `Ctrl + D`) the default drop down list for the *Folder* to displays last five folders in which the bookmarks were last saved. How to customize the number of folders displayed in the list? Also is it possible to remove the *Bookmark Toolbar* from the list?

Comment: Why don't you simply press the down arrow to the right of the drop-down menu to see all the folders?

Comment: @Karan I can do that, but that gives the complete list (not sorted by last bookmark folder) and then I need to scroll it find the subsequent folder/sub-folder. Right now this is what I do when I need to save bookmark in a folder not in the "quick list", but it is too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the answer you don't want to hear, but, no, it's not possible since it's the by-design behavior. You can see that even if you go to the 'All Bookmarks' library and right click any of the *default* elements, it won't give you the option of "Delete", nor the parent 'All Bookmarks' create a nested folder.

You can create a Feature Request over [Mozilla Bug Tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) to add such functionality, but that will be up to them to implement.

References:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/sort-bookmarks-quickly-find-ones-you-want#w_sorted-views-in-the-library-window

Source code responsible of creating the dialog box (aurora branch): http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-aurora/source/browser/components/places/content/controller.js#718

Answer (score 0):

There is a Firefox addon that seems to fulfill your requirement:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/change-bookmark-recent-folder-/

Apparently the version 1.1.0 does not properly work with Firefox ESR v31.2.0 running on a Debian GNU/Linux 7.7 (wheezy) 64-bit system.

Answer (score 0):

> Change Bookmark Recent Folder List Length 1.1.0.1
>
> Version 1. 1. 0 is not compatible with Firefox 40.0+. A new version,
>   1.2.1, which is compatible with Firefox 40.0+, is in the review queue. Until it is reviewed by Mozilla, you will need to install it from the
>   version history page.

So, I think, on been reviewed, we'll be finally able to increase number of recent folders.

There was an answer how to do it, but it didn't worked for 40.0.3 for me:

```
Open the Library (Ctrl+Shift+B).
On the left, expand the All Bookmarks section.
Left-click the Bookmarks Menu folder to select it.
On the top toolbar, click the Organize button and choose `New Bookmark`. 

Enter the following in the Location field for that bookmark. 
Change the value of maxResults if you want more or fewer than 20.

place:sort=12&maxResults=20&queryType=1

Either restart Firefox or just open a new window (Ctrl+N) and close the old one.
```

Because `New Bookmark` was inactive.